# How to select "Form webElement" in which the class changes?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-rc

```
<div _ngcontent-ucs-c11 class="order__form--name"> ==$0
 <label _ngcontent-ucs-c11 class="order__form--label">Symbol</label>
 <!---->
 <input _ngcontent-ucs-c11 class="form-control form-control-sm ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" formcontrolname="symbol" type="text" typeahead-editable="false" typeaheadoptionfield="symbolName"typeaheadoptionslimit="50">
 <!---->
 <!---->
</div>
```

I'm trying to send_Keys in selenium (python) but am unable to locate the text Web Element. I tried locating by class and xpath:

```
drive.find_element_by_class_name("form-control form-control-sm ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-star-inserted ng-touched")
```

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='form-control form-control-sm ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid')]")
```

The class changes from `"form-control form-control-sm ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-star-inserted ng-touched"` to `"form-control form-control-sm ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-star-inserted"`.
I'm not sure if this is significant but, in addition to this the `"_ngcontent-ucs-c11"` also changed to `"_ngcontent-uji-c7"` and might change again to something else.
Also, is it anyway related to `typeahead-editable="false"` attribute inside input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the dynamic element you can use regular expresions.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@name,'sel')]")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[starts-with (@name,'Tut')]")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[ends-with (@name,'nium')]")
```

Pick one that suits in your case(you will use (@class,'Tut')). And read more on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-regular-expressions-in-xpath-in-selenium-with-python